# How Scalding DSL translates into regular Scala code?

Tags: scala, dsl, scalding

Please help to find out how Scalding DSL translates into regular Scala code.

https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference#sortBy

For example:

```
val fasterBirds = birds.map('speed -> 'doubledSpeed) { speed : Int => speed * 2 }
```

Questions:

1. What conventions I need to follow to add my own functions to Scalding `map,`reduce, `groupBy,`sort and `scanLeft?
2. How Scalding translates expressions on fields like `'inpFld -> 'outFld to Scala code?
3. What data structures/functions Scalding translator creates? Where to find them in Scalding source code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That IS regular Scala code. One strength of Scala lies in its extensibility. The syntax allows the programmer to extend the syntax of programs to create domain-specific languages. This is especially helpful when using underlying libraries.

The domain-specific language of Scala doesn't translate so much as allow you to defer application of code until the appropriate time. The tick character (') means that the following set of characters is a *symbol*, built-in datatype. The `->` operator is syntactic sugar that can be expressed in the same way that a comma is, but visually, it imparts the concept of "translation" or "from this to that".

The domain-specific language you are looking at doesn't create structures, although it looks like it does create a functor. In this case it is a seen by the Java Virtual Machine as a `Function1[Type,Type]` instance which has an `apply` method that takes its argument and returns a result which is calculated by the provided code.

Comment: It would help to see what other code is required for `val fasterBirds = birds.map('speed -> 'doubledSpeed) { speed : Int => speed * 2 }` to be compiled without errors in Scala.

Comment: @om-nom-nom What part of Scala specification deals with using tick character (') to denote a symbol and -> operator as syntactic sugar? Where can I read about this? Thanks!

Comment: You might need to start at the beginning. Here is a good starting point: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/tour-of-scala.html

Comment: I know basic Scala, thanks. I was asking how this form `collection.fun('x->'g){...}` gets translated into regular function call, how arguments are get passed. I think `fun` should be a curried function and their should be some mechanism to pass the arguments as `symbols. I think somebody could give a rouigh example of this, no worries I will find myself.